# an internal counter in webgl?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I am learning WebGL by doing a simple drawing: a horizontal line and a vertical line, alternatively every 10 frames  (i.e 10 frames display a horizontal line, then the next 10 frames display a vertical line). I got that going by keeping a counter in js code, then give the vertex shader proper the coords on every frame. Is there a way to let the WebGL program to  handle this counter, instead of js? Is it possible to pass 4 points (of the 2 lines) to the WebGL program once, and make it handle the counting with some kind of variable that persists through every main interation?

I hope I can demonstrate better with the below code. The counter variable is what I am hoping for

```
attribute vec3 coordinates;
int counter = 0;
void main(void) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    if (counter < 10){
        gl_Position = vec4(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], 1.0);
    } else {
        gl_Position = vec4(coordinates[3], coordinates[4], coordinates[5], 1.0);
    }
    if (counter >= 20){
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

If that is not possible, please tell me how to handle this problem? Is passing the right vertices from js code the way to go?

Thank you very much for your attention. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just in case might I suggest [these articles on WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the counter from js as a `uniform`.

Your code will not work since counter is a local variable to the vertex shader and not sharing with other. Even it is shared, keep in mind that the vertex shader called in number of vertices time in any order.

Best practice is keeping shaders for rendering only and those logic in the application.

Comment: counter need to be increase in application and pass into the shader as uniform. Because the shader run multiple times per frame as I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you answer this small question as well? Say I need to draw 100.000 points. These points are generated from 1 single coord using a rule. What is the best way to draw these points? Using js to generate all these points then pass to a WebGL program, or pass the starting point coord and the rule to the program and let it does everything?

Comment: Can you describe the rule, for example. If you passing the initial point you also need to pass the 100000 vertices into the shader (just don’t need to calculate) and a vertex attribute to differentiate every vertex

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The question is just a way for me to try to understand WebGL's abilities. I dont really have a rule. But since you asked, please allow me to rephrase my question. Say, I have a line, 2 points, at the very left of a canvas, and I need to draw 100000 lines parallel to it, spacing evenly from the left end to the right end of the canvas. What is the best way to achieve this? Do I need to calculate 200.000 points in js, then pass them all to a WebGL program to draw? Or I can pass just the 2 first points, and use a vertex shader to calculate all the remaining points, then draw?

Comment: Passing 2 points and use calculator to make it 100000 lines is not possible in current version of WebGL 1.1.
You need to pass 2 points as uniform, and a list of 100000 vertex attributes (which can be the vertex index) then using the rule to produce 100000 vertex. It's depend on what kind of calculation so you can choose to do it in vertex shader or in application. (if it does change a lot, doing in vertex shader you will avoid calculating and updating the buffer all the time).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Since there is no other reply, I will accept your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In WebGL1 there is no counter. You'd have to pass one in. You can do this by filling a buffer with an increasing number and pass that in as an attribute to your vertex shader.

In WebGL2 there is a built in counter, `gl_VertexID` as well as `gl_InstanceID`

Whether or not you should be using counters depends on your use case. The normal way to draw a lot of points is to pass the points in as data via attributes.

The normal way to draw consecutive points right next to each other is to pass in vertices that generate a triangle that covers the points you want rendered.

Using the counters, either your own in WebGL1 or the built in ones in WebGL2 is fairly uncommon.

GLSL shaders have no state between one iteration and the next so your counter example won't work.

If you're new to WebGL might I suggest [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The site you mentioned was indeed what I used to learn WebGL.

Comment: If you do not mind, pls allow me to ask another question. Say I have 100k parallel lines, top to bottom. They're also equally spaced 2 px apart. The canvas is 1k px wide, so I can only display at most 500 lines. My question is how to best display these 500 lines? Should I calculate where the "camera" is in js code, and feed the coord of these 500 lines to a WebGL attribute variable every time the camera moves? Or is there a way to achieve this in the vertex shader (i.e pass 100k lines in at the start, then somehow only get the coord of the 500 visible lines and draw only those?).Thk in advance

Comment: I think you need ask another question, too little room here. You can't fit 100k lines on the screen so first thing is you should only draw what you can actually see if possible. Whether you try to do it all in the vertex shader or more traditional methods really depends on the specifics. Doing things all in the vertex shader is usually far less flexible so it just really depends on **EXACTLY** what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want to see some shaders drawing things 100% in the vertex shader see https://vertexshaderart.com

Comment: These are just theoretical situations for me to understand WebGL. There is no exact goal, really :) Thank you, gman, for helping out.